# Random forcing does not add Cohen real.

Tags: logic, forcing

I know that random forcing does not add unbounded reals. Is a Cohen real always unbounded?

I can proof that the product of two random forcings adds a Cohen real. How can I show that the two step iteration of random forcings does not add cohen real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cohen reals are unbounded, this is fairly straightforward to show when presenting the Cohen forcing with $\omega^{<\omega}$ rather than $2^{<\omega}$.

Suppose that $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ is in the ground model, and let $\dot c$ be the canonical name for the Cohen real, so for any $p\in\omega^{<\omega}$ and $n<\omega$ we can find $m>n$ and $q\leq p$ such that $q(m)>f(m)$, simply by letting $m=\max\operatorname{dom} p+1$ and setting $q=p\cup\{(m,f(m)+1)\}$, for example.

This shows that $\bf 1$ already forces that $\check f$ does not dominate $\dot c$. Therefore this holds for any $f$ in the ground model, so $\dot c$ is unbounded. $\square$

---

For the iteration of random reals, show that it is isomorphic to adding a single random real by showing that the measure algebra is the same measure algebra.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Even though your suggestion gives a lot more information about the iteration, it now came some other way to prove my second question. Let $f:\omega\to\omega$ be any new real added in the iteration. We know that the rangom forcing is $\omega^\omega$-bounding, so there is some function $g_1:\omega\to\omega$ in the intermediate model dominating $f$, by the same argument there is a function on the ground model $g_2:\omega\to\omega$ dominating $g_1$ (and so $f$), hence the iteration does not add unbounded reals.